# Training Faster R-CNN or Mask R-CNN with Windows Anaconda prerequisites in example

Tags: python, r, keras, conda, faster-rcnn

I am not experienced user in Python. I have been working with R for the years, but keras implemented there doesn't provide any reproducible examples of working with object detection architectures like Faster R-CNN. I found a lot of examples that harness Python, but I faced troubles just even run some examples from the first lines: it is all built on the downloading through `pip` operator (in terminal in Ubuntu or orther Linux OS), while **analogues for Windows conda users are not provided**.

That is, I even don't know how to install module mrcnn from the one example on my Windows machine. Should I suffer further? I have had a very bad experience trying launch compatible versions of CUDA, cudNN and other things for my keras on Ubuntu. And now I am returning to the Windows, but... keras in R still doesn't provide any suggestions for object detection techniques.

Does somebody have links for Faster or Mask R-CNN implementation with conda examples for downloading prerequisites? My googling is failed here. Or in R-keras.

Comment: Have you looked at this https://github.com/noelcodes/Mask_RCNN? In the README, it shows how to get to run in Conda.

Comment: Ahmad, I followed this tutorial but aftecr creating an environment I faced this error trying to install requirements.txt: ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

Comment: `requirements.txt` is available here https://github.com/noelcodes/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/Mask_RCNN/requirements.txt

Make sure to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside `Mask_RCNN/` directory or run `pip install -r Mask_RCNN/requirements.txt`

Comment: Yes, I chose this environment. But it didnt work anyway. Probably I should better install Ubuntu and do not suffer with these things.